# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId In Mongo DB for @Path Rest API

Tags: mongodb, rest, path, database

I am using @Path annotation to fetch data on the basis of 'State' parameter from mongo DB. While executing the code, I am getting the above exception.

The code:

```
//State.Java
    @GET  
    @Path("/{State}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object[] addBuild2(@PathParam("State") String State  ) throws UnknownHostException
          
    { System.out.println("ïnside Location");
    Location loc = new Location();
    
    List<DBObject> basicDBList=(List<DBObject>) loc.getState2();
        System.out.println("ïnside State2===>"+basicDBList);
        return basicDBList.toArray();
        
    }

//Location.Java
public List<DBObject> getState2() throws UnknownHostException {
    DB db=ConnectToDB.getConnection();
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("location");
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
     List<BasicDBObject> andQuery = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
     andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("Country", "USA"));
    
  andQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("State", new ObjectId("State")));
   obj.put("$and", andQuery); 
    

    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
        fields.put("_id", 0);
        
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(obj, fields);
        List<DBObject> obj1 =cursor.toArray();
    
        
        
        System.out.println(""+obj1);
            }
        
        return obj1;
}
}
```

The Stack trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [State]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [State]
    org.bson.types.ObjectId.parseHexString(ObjectId.java:519)
    org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:233)
    com.speed.infoaxon.Location.getState2(Location.java:116)
    com.speed.infoaxon.GetProjectLocationResponse.addBuild2(GetProjectLocationResponse.java:54)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Please tell what the issue is while using @Path for Rest API as I am using 'State' as a parameter to fetch all the data for the corresponding state.

Comment: The error is pretty specific. `new ObjectId("State")` is completely incorrect and is not a "hexadecimal representation of an `ObjectId` value". What do you think you are trying to do? Show the document you expect to match and by what conditions.

Comment: Thanks, my document is as below:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599426b35a29291d2a325cfb"),
    "Country" : "USA",
    "State" : "MA",
    "ZipCode" : 1003,
    "ClimateZone" : "5A",
    "EnergyCode" : "IECC 2015"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599426b35a29291d2a325cfc"),
    "Country" : "USA",
    "State" : "MA",
    "ZipCode" : 1004,
    "ClimateZone" : "5A",
    "EnergyCode" : "IECC 2015"
}



and I want to get all the ZipCodes on the basis of States in the  country US

Comment: Please use the ["edit link"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46030282/edit) on your question to add details. `"State"` contains "string" data and is not an `ObjectId`. I suggest you [read some documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) and get acquainted with the basic query syntax. The code here looks like you copied and example without understanding the principles first. Read and understand the basics. Then move on to understanding the [Java Driver syntax.](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/)